# Set Edittext Background per Line

Tags: java, android, textview

I would like to set the background of edittext per line as opposed to android's block style of setting up the background i.e when a user writes some text, I should get the text entered by a user, split it into lines and set a background color for each line. Check the attached picture for references.
I've not been able to figure out how to achieve the same, please help. This is what I've done so far, thanks in advance.
Desired picture  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhpTQ.jpg

```
 String allLines = userInput.getText().toString(); // userInput is an edittext field
        String[] lines;
        String linelimit =  "\n";

        lines= allLines.split(linelimit);

        //this gives the lines in the user input text][1]][1]
```

Comment: Add your desired output picture

Comment: hey @sanoJ I have..kindly check. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 or more separate TextView/EditText instead. If number of lines are different during execution then add Textview/EditText dynamically in LinearLayout.

It is not possible in any view (that I know of) because there is only one background for every view, or EditText and cannot be separated for each line.

If you are using an EditText that user can edit, then you will have to calculate width of EditText as text changes and if its width exceeds a limit, you can add another EditText below it.